# How do I recover from a `tmux a` by mistake within a tmux session?

Tags: shell, tmux

I have a tmux session with a pair of windows. I want to recover the stdout from both those windows. I found [this example](http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/capture-tmux-output-the-much-less-painful-way/), and so, within my existing attached session, ran `tmux a`. I now have a screen full of tilde (~).

tmux is still responsive - I can swap between windows, but still see a wall of ~.

What have I done? How do I recover?

System details:

`vagrant@precise32:~$ uname -a
Linux precise32 3.2.0-23-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:19:09 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
vagrant@precise32:~$ tmux -V
tmux 1.6`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can skip step 1 in those instructions if you're already attached via tmux.  To detach the one you added, you can use <kbd>C-b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.  Hopefully that will leave you with a session that's missing the tildes, and from which you can then capture output.

Also, depending on the use case you're trying to get overall, you might also want to look at things like [script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script), which can capture output (and input) from a shell session.  (It may or may not be a match for your needs, just showing other possibilities that may be useful.)